# How do I read from a server-side binary file in Blazor?

Tags: file, directory, blazor, blazor-server-side

After some user input, I want to read data from a binary file and write a response. I've put the binary file in the App_data folder like this:

[image: Solution Explorer]

I can't figure out how specify the directory where the binary file resides:

```
   const String BODIST_DATA_FILENAME = "~/App_Data/BoDistData.dat";
   using FileStream dataFs = new FileStream(BODIST_DATA_FILENAME, FileMode.Open, FileAccess.Read);
```

The project is a Blazor App
[image]

Comment: The short answer probaly is to omit that `~/`. If that doesn't work, inject `IHostingEnvironment` into your page or service.

Comment: That worked! I don't see how to mark this as answered though.

Comment: Which one worked?  You can post a self-answer.

Answer (score 1):

Omitting the ~/ worked.

```
const String BODIST_DATA_FILENAME = "App_Data/BoDistData.dat";
```